# Migrating custom routes from v2 to v3

Tags: url, routing

I have a handful of custom routes configured on this project like

`'action/(?P<custom_id>[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6})/(?P<slug>.*)' => 'action/_member',`

If I'm reading the docs correctly, then those need to change to become

```
'action/<custom_id:[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}>/<entrySlug:{slug}.*>' => [
        'template' => 'action/_member'
    ],
```

but that gives me a template not found error when I hit `localhost/action/L100582/&session=115`

If I simplify the rule to become

`action/steven' => [ 'template' => 'action/_member' ]`

and hit, `localhost/action/steven` the template loads just fine.

I can't wrap my little head around what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

The `{slug}` token you’re using there is going to get replaced with Craft’s slug pattern:

```
(?:[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\.\_\-]+)
```

Since that’s not an optional pattern, the resulting regex isn’t going to match your example URL, which doesn’t have a slug after the `custom_id`.

I’d recommend you use two separate routes that both point to the same template:

```php
'action/<custom_id:[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}>' => ['template' => 'action/_member'],
'action/<custom_id:[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}>/<entrySlug:{slug}>' => ['template' => 'action/_member'],
```

(And just in case it wasn’t intentional, worth pointing out that the slug is going to be called `entrySlug` as opposed to `slug` with that route, which is another change from your Craft 2 route. Use `<slug:{slug}>` if you didn’t mean to change the name.)